# Safari 16.4 seems to lose session cookies on asset requests or javascript fetches

Tags: macos, ios, ipad, safari, ipados

On iPads after updating to iPadOS 16.4, Safari often "looses" the session cookie provided by PlayFramework: When the browser requests assets (js scripts) or when additional data is fetched by JavaScript, the session cookie is not included in the request.

These secondary requests will redirect through our IAM because no session cookie is present. The IAM redirects back to the original domain with a payload so that the login session can be resumed. A new Set-Cookie header is sent in the response with the new session cookie.

This causes the framework to issue a new CSRF token (that is part of the session cookie) which is different from the old one that was already rendered into a hidden form input. The browser stores this new token and includes it when it POSTs the form. The token in the body of the request is now different from the one in the cookies, causing the CSRF check to fail.

We have tried different devices (Android, Windows, MacBook, and iPads) on different versions. The problem only occurs with Safari on iPad/MacBook running version 16.4, 16.4.1, or 16.5 beta. The problem cannot be reproduced using Chrome on iPad. Furthermore, the problem does not occur with private browsing in Safari.

Some things we ruled out:

- Same behaviour on devices managed by MDM and on open devices.
- PlayFramework version is now updated to the latest 2.8 version.
- Using a separate cookie for the CSRF token (instead of the play session cookie) does not make a difference either.
- Modifying the Cache-Control header to cache responses more aggressively or not at all does not help.

Has anyone also experienced this or similar problems?

Comment: What concretely do you see when this happens? Is it saying "CSRF check failed" or "vulnerable/dangerous website/tab/brower" or something similar?

Comment: @Thinkr Play Framework renders a grey page with the message  "Unauthorized". HTTP status is 403 Forbidden.

The same error page as in the screenshot of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44176942/controller-post-action-responds-unauthorized

Comment: Have you tried clearing Cookies and Cache?

Comment: Does the issue occur with all websites, or just one in particular?

Comment: Clearing website data does not fix the issue.
The issue occurs with all Web Apps we developed using PlayFramework.
What could lead to v16.4 losing the browser session/cookies?

Comment: I am unfortunately do not think me able to provide you with an answer that would resolve your problem. Do you have any extensions running that could parasitate cookie saving?

Comment: @Thinkr Thanks for your help. There are no extensions an we have also tried toggling options like cross site tracking.

Comment: Good luck then, I'll still try to solve this problem though.

Answer (score 2):

I'm experiencing this problem too. On iOS and also macOS.

The consensus seems to be that this is a Webkit bug that was recently introduced. Here is the bug report:

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=255524